# Error convert string to date : ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, date, classcastexception

I`m trying to convert a string to date:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date dataEvento = null;

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
dataEvento = (Date)dateFormat.parse("28/08/2010"); //the app crash here
```

**LogCat:**

```
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ladessa.jccb/com.ladessa.jccb.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663) 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679) 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033) 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at com.ladessa.jccb.MainActivity.createScheduledNotification(MainActivity.java:59) 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at com.ladessa.jccb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:110) 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627) 
03-06 10:06:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Crashes with what? Please show stack trace.

Comment: Why are you casting the result of parse to a Date when it's a date already?

Comment: The Thom, I remove the cast and import java.utils.date instead of java.sql.date and it works

Comment: Excellent. Please accept one of the answers below, then.

Comment: @illDev: In future, please make sure that you include relevant context - in this case at least the stack trace - when you ask a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the below line...

```
(Date)formatter.parse(str)
```

You are trying cast `java.util.Date` type `Date` object to `java.sql.Date` type `Date` object...that's why its throwing this `Exception`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

And its causing due to import of the below package...

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

You should import the package as below...So, you should remove the above import and import this below one.

```
import java.util.Date;
```

Comment: How do you know that? There's nothing about `java.sql.Date` in the question, and no indication of the error...

Comment: cause...I also faced the same problem.

Comment: It's possible that the cast to a `Date` is an indicator there's a type mismatch

Comment: Well you may have faced *a* problem with somewhat similar symptoms, but I think you're making an assumption that it's the *same* problem. Now that we have the exception, I *suspect* you're correct - but I think it would have been wise to be a bit more circumspect than: "you have imported the below package"...

Comment: I remove the cast and import java.utils.date instead of java.sql.date and it works

Comment: @BenPearson...you get the point why I'm directly indicating to the `import` issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change libraries :) `java.sql.Date to java.util.Date` ;) this might help.

Comment: This looks remarkably similar to Hamid's answer, but I don't see any imports in the question at all... where did you get the information that the OP is using `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: Maybye, but at the begening I had the same problems. So it is common mistake. But post might be released in the same time, I didn't see above answer first.

Answer (score 1):

Its importing wrong library prob dude just use this

```
import java.util.Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
String Stringdate = "28/08/2010";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date convertedDate = new Date();
try {
    convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(Stringdate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.err.println("Date Conversion Error : " + e.getMessage());
}
System.out.println(convertedDate);
```